# How to start IntelliJ plugin (IntelliBot)

Tags: robotframework, intellij-plugin

I've managed to import the jar file for the Robotframework editor IntelliBot in ItelliJ but now I'm not sure how to start it. I tried to make a new project but there is no IntelliBot option. How do I actually see this editor?

Answer (score 0):

The `IntelliBot` is only a plugin and not a standalone editor in itself. After you have installed the plugin for PyCharm, restart the IDE and create you project. Files with `.robot` extension will automatically start supporting syntax highlighting. Full set of features are available [here](https://github.com/millennialmedia/intellibot/wiki/Features).